# How to filter menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a project with a website for food catering. Where it shows all the products and has a filter tool to more accurately find what the user is looking for. I want it to be 15 products per page, with a page scrolling feature, to not have too many products making the page very long.

I'm so far only working on making it work, the issue I am having is that whenever I select any of the categories it only shows the products that were originally on the current page. It doesn't update and make it so that there is 15 products per page.

---

**Example: Selecting salty products.**

[Page with no categories selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be79Y.png)

[Page with "Salty" selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVkA8.png)

It keeps the items on the their original page, but how do I make it so that the items from the next pages move over and fill up the first page (15 products).

---

Hopefully I explained my problem well enough.
Thanks for any help!

Here's my current code:

```js
const categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".category-filter");
const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product");
const prevPageButton = document.getElementById("prevPage");
const nextPageButton = document.getElementById("nextPage");
let currentPage = 1;
const productsPerPage = 15;

categoryCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProducts);
});

function updateProducts() {
  const selectedCategories = Array.from(categoryCheckboxes)
    .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
    .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

  products.forEach((product, index) => {
    const productCategories = product.className
      .split(" ")
      .filter((className) => className !== "product");

    if (
      selectedCategories.length === 0 ||
      selectedCategories.some((category) =>
        productCategories.includes(category)
      )
    ) {
      if (
        index >= (currentPage - 1) * productsPerPage &&
        index < currentPage * productsPerPage
      ) {
        product.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        product.style.display = "none";
      }
    } else {
      product.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  updatePagination();
}

function updatePagination() {
  const totalProducts = products.length;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalProducts / productsPerPage);

  if (currentPage > 1) {
    prevPageButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    prevPageButton.disabled = true;
  }

  if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    nextPageButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    nextPageButton.disabled = true;
  }
}

prevPageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (currentPage > 1) {
    currentPage--;
    updateProducts();
  }
});

nextPageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const totalProducts = products.length;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalProducts / productsPerPage);
  if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    currentPage++;
    updateProducts();
  }
});
updateProducts();
```

```css
.product {
  display: block;
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Food Catering Menu</h1>

<label for="salty">Salty</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="salty" class="category-filter" value="salty" />

<label for="sweet">Sweet</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="sweet" class="category-filter" value="sweet" />

<label for="sandwich">Sandwich</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="sandwich" class="category-filter" value="sandwich" />

<label for="salad">Salad</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="salad" class="category-filter" value="salad" />

<label for="fruits">Fruits</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="fruits" class="category-filter" value="fruits" />

<div class="products">
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 1
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 2</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 3</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 4</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 5</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 6
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 7</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 8
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 9</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 10</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 11</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 12</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 13
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 14</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 15</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 16
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 17</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 18</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 19</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 20</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 21
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 22</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 23
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 24</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 25</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 26</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 27</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 28
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 29</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 30</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 31
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 32</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 33</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 34</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 35</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 36
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 37</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 38
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 39</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 40</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 41</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 42</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 43
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 44</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 45</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 46
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 47</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 48</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 49</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 50</div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
  <button id="prevPage">Previous Page</button>
  <button id="nextPage">Next Page</button>
</div>
```

I have tried different things, but it always either breaks or displays all the products on one page...

Comment: I'd hide all the products, and cloned the matching product elements to bunches of 15 in "pages", then show a single page with the buttons.

Comment: The problem is that the `index` you are checking for being inside the current page boundaries, is the index of the _unfiltered_ products. You can work around that, by keeping your own counter of _shown_ products (`let shownProducts = 0;` before the loop, check on that instead of `index` in your if condition, and do `shownProducts++` only in the if branch, when a product gets shown.)

Comment: But then your pagination buttons will also be "off", because in your `updatePagination` function, you are also working based on the number of _all_ products, not the currently shown amount - so you will need to modify that part accordingly as well then. (And same inside the `nextPageButton` click handler.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I'll try to implement this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more sophisticated approach to this would IMHO be, to leverage the power of CSS selectors a bit more.

I am using the [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) pseudo class here, which already has good browser support.

We use `.product` as our base product selector here - and then if any checkboxes where checked, we append `:where(.checkboxvalue1, .checkboxvalue2, ...)` to that, with `checkboxvalueX` being the actual values of those checkboxes (which correspond to the product class names.)

Then we first hide all products, and then only show the appropriate number of filtered products for the current page number again. Instead of manipulating inline styles directly, I used the class `filtered` here to hide those items that are currently filtered *out*, not shown.)

And then the code to update your pagination buttons, can access the length of the *filtered* products directly.

```js
const categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".category-filter");
const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product");
const prevPageButton = document.getElementById("prevPage");
const nextPageButton = document.getElementById("nextPage");
let currentPage = 1;
const productsPerPage = 15;
let filteredProducts = products;

categoryCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProducts);
});

function updateProducts() {
  const selectedCategories = Array.from(categoryCheckboxes)
    .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
    .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

  let productSelector = '.product';

  if (selectedCategories.length !== 0) {
    productSelector += ':where(.' + selectedCategories.join(', .') + ')'
  }
  //console.log(productSelector)

  products.forEach((product, index) => {
    product.classList.add('filtered');
  });
  filteredProducts = document.querySelectorAll(productSelector);

  currentPage = Math.min(currentPage, Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / productsPerPage));

  filteredProducts.forEach((product, index) => {
    if (
      index >= (currentPage - 1) * productsPerPage &&
      index < currentPage * productsPerPage
    ) {
      product.classList.remove('filtered');
    }
  })


  updatePagination();
}

function updatePagination() {
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / productsPerPage);

  if (currentPage > 1) {
    prevPageButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    prevPageButton.disabled = true;
  }

  if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    nextPageButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    nextPageButton.disabled = true;
  }
}

prevPageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (currentPage > 1) {
    currentPage--;
    updateProducts();
  }
});

nextPageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / productsPerPage);
  if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    currentPage++;
    updateProducts();
  }
});
updateProducts();
```

```css
.product {
  display: block;
}

.product.filtered {
  display: none;
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Food Catering Menu</h1>

<label for="salty">Salty</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="salty" class="category-filter" value="salty" />

<label for="sweet">Sweet</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="sweet" class="category-filter" value="sweet" />

<label for="sandwich">Sandwich</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="sandwich" class="category-filter" value="sandwich" />

<label for="salad">Salad</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="salad" class="category-filter" value="salad" />

<label for="fruits">Fruits</label>
<input style="margin-right: 20px" type="checkbox" id="fruits" class="category-filter" value="fruits" />

<div class="products">
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 1
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 2</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 3</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 4</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 5</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 6
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 7</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 8
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 9</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 10</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 11</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 12</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 13
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 14</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 15</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 16
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 17</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 18</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 19</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 20</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 21
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 22</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 23
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 24</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 25</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 26</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 27</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 28
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 29</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 30</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 31
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 32</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 33</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 34</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 35</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 36
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 37</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 38
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 39</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 40</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 41</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 42</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 43
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 44</div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 45</div>
  <div style="color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="product salty">
    Salty Food 46
  </div>
  <div class="product sweet">Sweet Food 47</div>
  <div class="product sandwich">Sandwich 48</div>
  <div class="product salad">Salad 49</div>
  <div class="product fruits">Fruit 50</div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
  <button id="prevPage">Previous Page</button>
  <button id="nextPage">Next Page</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If the current browser compatibility of `:where()` is not satisfactory, then that part could also be rewritten to create a selector in the form `.product.salty, .product.sweet` instead.

Comment: One tiny edit: By unchecking a filter checkbox again, this could produce a situation where you are left with an "empty" page, because currentPage is now greater than the number of pages resulting form the _new_ list of filtered products. That can be fixed by correcting the currentPage accordingly, before the products for the current page are made visible again: `currentPage = Math.min(currentPage, Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / productsPerPage));` (already added in the above example now.)